# Uploading word/pdf file only and storing the link on a database through a model in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, web, model-binding

I have a form that is supposed to take the user's credentials and his resume. PDF/DOC

I already have a database where I plan to store the server path to the uploaded file as a string

I generated a strongly typed view that takes in the file via

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.file, new { type = "file" })%>
```

I have created a HttpPostedFileBase object in the model. And the model.file is supposed to store HttpPostedFileBase file object.

But in the controller when I try to get the model.file object, I get null as its value.

What am I doing wrong. Why is model binding not binding file upload ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to form options

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", 
    "Controller", 
    FormMethod.Post, 
    new 
    { 
        id = "form", enctype="multipart/form-data" 
    }))
{

}
```